# Some users perform edits to remove the tag [pine-script-4] from questions that I tagged

Tags: support, tags

As a trader I am closely following various trading platforms and their related tags; for example, [metatrader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metatrader), [mt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mt4), [tradingview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tradingview).

For *Tradingview* there is a scripting language called Pinescript which has been around for a few years. However, it was updated last year, from version 3 to version 4. The issue is that version 4 is not at all backwards compatible with version 3; they are essentially different scripting languages. For this reason I created the new tag [pine-script-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pine-script-4). The same day I did that, a number of people started using it (since they know about the differences).

However, two persons on SO have decided to serial kill my new tag, and keep editing and removing this tag from every single question. I think this is  wrong.

What can I do to prevent and report this behavior?

(Alternatively, perhaps it is I who am doing something wrong, in which case I would like some constructive feedback.)

Comment: Rollback the edits that remove the tag. If you notice the same user doing the edits, flag an edited post for moderator attention, and explain the situation in the available text box.

Comment: "I would like some constructive feedback": regardless of the rights or wrongs of the tag edits, accepting constructive feedback isn't obvious when saying things like "This is just plain stupid and seem to indicate they they're just trying to collect SO editing points."

Comment: Both great points. As heretic suggested, I did exactly that, but then i noticed they did it on every single question marked. So I came here. 
Yes, you can also sense my irritation there as well. But reality is, that it is like removing the C# tag from a C related question and back-tag it as C. Simply seem a bit ignorant, which is why this is an issue at all.

Comment: The user who removed the tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828610/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-at-a-certain-time-in-pinescript-on-tradingview) seems to be competent with the technology. I'm not saying the are right, but you can consider that maybe they could be onto something. They are not "stalking" you, they are curating a part of the site they care about.

Comment: @yivi Yes. that's surprising to me too. I can only mention, that (for example) almost all *strategies* coded in V3 is using `n` to designate the current bar index, has been renamed to `bar_index`, essentially rendering every single v3 code incompatible. Then of course one can argue with, well: if you change the `//version=4` to 3, you can still run it. Yes, you can but then you're not using v4.

Comment: It seems like an employee for the PineCoders company is one of the ones removing the tag. Have you engaged in any kind of dialogue with these users to ask why they disagree with you? It's not uncommon for companies to outsource the support for their product to SO; maybe this is causing them some confusion?

Comment: Note that [tag:pine-script-4] does not have any usage guidelines nor info... which would be perfect place to put most information from this post... whether it would have helped to this particular issue I don't know but definitely would not hurt.

Comment: Sorry guys, I will no longer engage in any further communication with you here, because both my posts and comments are being ether changed or censored, while being down-voted without any reason or explanation whatsoever, contrary to SO's very own recommendations. A very sad support request indeed.

Comment: The reasons for removing were covered here and 
 I kindly asked to edit the question and 
 remove the tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59828610/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-at-a-certain-time-in-pinescript-on-tradingview#comment105910835_59828610 But `not2qubit` disagree and deems that he knows better than real pine-programmers what `pine-script` is.

Comment: No one has removed any of your posts. Your comment complaining about downvotes was removed, as is our standard practice. Such comments are noise and regularly removed by moderators. This is not censorship. No one is supposed to leave comments about votes, whether down or up. Voting is anonymous by design. Providing comments to explain downvotes has been suggested many times, but [is not going to happen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357436). It is quite obvious why this was downvoted, of course. You came in with guns blazing, and that annoyed folks. Easy to fix next time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may well have a legitimate concern here, but please consider toning down the rhetoric and not taking everything personally. Folks don't dedicate their free time to helping to keep this site clean (and making the relatively-feeble tag system work well takes a *lot* of dedication) because they're trying to collect points. In fact, after earning [full edit privileges at 2k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), one doesn't even earn any points for retagging questions. It is actually quite a thankless job.

So, chances are, this is just a misunderstanding. We tend to look upon version-specific tags with a healthy amount of skepticism here, because they tend to be created unnecessarily and are the source of a variety of issues in light of the limitations of our tagging system. There are, however, cases where version-specific tags are useful, and that is precisely the situation you described: where there were substantial changes between versions and there are a significant number of questions being asked about that particular version.

If you can provide me with a list of questions that you think deserve the [pine-script-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pine-script-4) tag, then I'll be happy to re-tag those for you, and even reach out to the users who have been removing the tag to make sure that they see this discussion (and chime in if they disagree that the tag is needed).

Comment: Thank you Cody for explaining. I came here early, so the tag has not been around long enough to cause any damage. But I'll point the guys here, when/if I see it next time. To be noted, is that I believe from now on all new Pinescript code will be of version 4, unless someone tried to copy/modify old version 3 code. Which is why the new tag is important.

Comment: Cody, none of the questions deserve the new tag. Current version of pine-script is 4 and the other aren't supported. `not2qubit` by some reasons has created a new tag and we, people who track the tag and give vast majority of answers for those questions, asked him to remove it, because it requires additional work from us and confuses new users. But `not2qubit` replied that we are lazy if we don't won't to make that additional work. I'm asking to remove the new tag. And `not2qubit` should respect other people's efforts in helping users, because we spend our free time on that.

Comment: @Michel I appreciate your input, but it doesn’t belong in a comment. Please post an answer here explaining why you think the tag is unwarranted. As for the attitude of this particular user, I tend to agree, but let’s try to leave that out of it. If you post an answer explaining why the tag is unnecessary, that’s useful to be able to refer others to in the future as a justification for removing the tag. Again, I appreciate subject-matter experts weighing in here. It is essential for us moderators, who don’t know everything.